# How to to remove all spaces in href attribute with regular expression in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, regexp-replace

I have a WordPress database for post contents containing some links which have extra spaces added in between the **href** attribute which I want them removed.

So

```
<a href="/condition/ # how">text</a>
```

should become:

```
<a href="/condition/#how">text</a>
```

I tried using REGEXP_REPLACE but not working:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content=REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '/href="\s"/gi', '') 
WHERE post_content REGEXP '/href="\s"/gi'
```

MySQL version 5.6.44

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your REGEXP to match ALL spaces. There is good old expression to match all whitespaces in the given attribute (in your case it is `href`).

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|href=")[^"\s]*\K(?:\s|"(*SKIP)(*F))
```

This expression matches all-white spaces inside quotes of `href` attribute. I made [a demo example of working solution](https://regex101.com/r/8ijz7p/2) for you.

Comment: I changed it to: UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content=REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '/(?:\G(?!\A)|href=")[^"\s]*\K(?:\s|"(*SKIP)(*F))/gi', '') 
WHERE post_content REGEXP '/(?:\G(?!\A)|href=")[^"\s]*\K(?:\s|"(*SKIP)(*F))/gi'    but I got an error: 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: Artem, can you update my SQL statement to accommodate it? I can't get it working..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this plugin in order to search and replace blanks for nothing insto href="" param.

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Please, you should create a backup of your database before apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks but my question is about the correct MySQL statement with REGEXP_REPLACE.